# Scala Play project fails build after adding swagger-play2 dependency - sbt cannot find play?

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.2, travis-ci, swagger

I created a [sandbox play project](https://github.com/pathikrit/play-test) for testing. It was [building and passing the tests](https://travis-ci.org/pathikrit/play-test/builds) on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/). I added dependency on [swagger-play2](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/modules/swagger-play2) and it started failing the tests with error message:

```
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.1!play_2.10.jar(src)
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create [default play scala project](https://github.com/pathikrit/play-test/commits/master)
2. [Build passes](https://travis-ci.org/pathikrit/play-test/builds/17714513) before adding swagger
3. [Adding](https://github.com/pathikrit/play-test/commit/d8ad88083b56dd0269eaefc30025a42f54f0dba5) [swagger](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.wordnik/swagger-play2_2.10/1.3.2) to `build.sbt`
4. Build now [fails :(](https://travis-ci.org/pathikrit/play-test/builds/17714900)
5. [Remove](https://github.com/pathikrit/play-test/commit/862943da5162b12b36e0937fe9068db0e29090f4) swagger dependency
6. Build now [passes](https://travis-ci.org/pathikrit/play-test/builds/17714513) again!

It seems strange adding dependency on swagger would trigger this build failure. What am I doing wrong? Feel free to send a pull request on the [github project](https://github.com/pathikrit/play-test) if you want to test your fixes ((Travis should auto build your pull request).

Complete GitHub project history: https://github.com/pathikrit/play-test/commits/master

Complete Travis-CI build history: https://travis-ci.org/pathikrit/play-test/builds

Commit that triggers build failure: https://github.com/pathikrit/play-test/commit/d8ad88083b56dd0269eaefc30025a42f54f0dba5

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my personal Macbook. Either because of the different way I installed play (`brew install play` vs [Travis's manual script](https://github.com/pathikrit/play-test/blob/master/.travis.yml) OR because of local ivy/m2/play caches? How do I completely remove all local play jar caches so I can force a reinstall? What other reason would make this bug appear in Travis only and not locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have a script to setup the dependencies:

```
PLAY_VERSION=2.2.1
wget http://downloads.typesafe.com/play/${PLAY_VERSION}/play-${PLAY_VERSION}.zip
      unzip play-${PLAY_VERSION}.zip -d ${HOME}
      # Manually populate the play directory with missing jars - TODO: remove this hack (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361621/)
      SCALA_VERSION=2.10
      MAVEN_PLAY=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/com/typesafe/play/play_${SCALA_VERSION}/${PLAY_VERSION}/play_${SCALA_VERSION}-${PLAY_VERSION}
      LOCAL_REPO=${HOME}/play-${PLAY_VERSION}/repository/local/com.typesafe.play/play_${SCALA_VERSION}/${PLAY_VERSION}
      mkdir ${LOCAL_REPO}/srcs/ ${LOCAL_REPO}/poms/
      wget ${MAVEN_PLAY}.pom --output-document ${LOCAL_REPO}/poms/play_${SCALA_VERSION}.pom
      wget ${MAVEN_PLAY}-sources.jar --output-document ${LOCAL_REPO}/srcs/play_${SCALA_VERSION}-sources.jar
      wget ${MAVEN_PLAY}-test-sources.jar --output-document ${LOCAL_REPO}/srcs/play_${SCALA_VERSION}-test-sources.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the Typesafe repository is missing.

Check your project/plugins.sbt, tipically it contains the sbt-plugin inclusion and the needed typesafe repo resolution:

```
// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
```

Comment: No, I have that in my `project/plugins.sbt` - please take a look [here](https://github.com/pathikrit/play-test/tree/master/project)

Answer (score 1):

please update your dependencies to use swagger-play2-1.3.3:

```
"com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.3.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hackily fixed build by [manually downloading all the jars in my travis build script](https://github.com/pathikrit/play-test/blob/655f98a1c5da3c9a00f2070ecb1f919c7641acab/.travis.yml). But, I doubt that is the real solution - it seems adding `swagger-play2` assumes some jars to be in a particular directory and never resolves to anywhere else...

Answer (score 0):

Swagger 1.3.1 works with Play 2.2.1 for me.